# Not Moving to next Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

Hi In my application login form with username and password checking username and password existing in the database or not.If Exist means showing one text message user found and I want to move to next activity.otherwise No such user found.

Now,clicking login button it's showing user found and not moving to next activity.

Can any one please help me to resolve this issuse.

**Login.java**

```
  public class Login extends Activity {
    Button login;
    private static final Pattern USERNAME_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,250}");
    private static final Pattern PASSWORD_PATTERN = Pattern
            .compile("[a-zA-Z0-9+_.]{4,16}");
    EditText usname,pword;
    TextView tv;

    String username,password;
    HttpPost httppost;
    StringBuffer buffer;
    String data="";
    HttpResponse response;
    HttpClient httpclient;
    CheckBox mCbShowPwd;
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.login);  
        usname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
        pword= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);
        mCbShowPwd = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbShowPwd);

       mCbShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if (!isChecked) {

                    pword.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                } else {

                     pword.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
                }
            }
        });

       login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String username = usname.getText().toString();
               String password = pword.getText().toString();
               if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {
                   if (username.equals("")) {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER USERNAME",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }
                   if (password.equals("")) {
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER PASSWORD",
                               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                   }

               } else if (!CheckUsername(username) && !CheckPassword(password)){
                       Toast.makeText(Login.this, "ENTER VALID USERNAME & PASSWORD",
                             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
               else{
                   final String queryString = "username=" + username + "&password="
                    + password;
                   final String data = DatabaseUtility.executeQueryPhp("login",queryString);

            System.out.println("data :: "+data);
         tv.setText("Response from PHP : " + data);
            if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
            {
               Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);
               startActivity(i);           
            }
            else
            {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User not found, check query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
               }                    

            }
         });


    }

            private boolean CheckPassword(String password) {

                return PASSWORD_PATTERN.matcher(password).matches();
            }

            private boolean CheckUsername(String username) {

                return USERNAME_PATTERN.matcher(username).matches();
            }

    }
```

Comment: have you define Home activity in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent(Login.this, Home.class);` try it.

Comment: yes added in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Is it giving any errors? If so please post the logcat trace.

Comment: No error In else condition I wrote one if condition i.e not working

Comment: can you checkout that line please

Comment: outside it's moving to next activity

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing

```
<activity
  android:name="package_name.Home"></activity>
```

In `AndroidManifest.xml`

You must define all activities in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

**EDIT**

```
System.out.println("data :: "+data);
if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found"))
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);
   startActivity(i);           
}
else
{
   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"User not found, check query", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: @user3436185 you have to add logcat details in question. Are you able to see toast with login successfull text?

Comment: @user3436185 then data variable is not "User Found". you should check data variable value first, `System.out.println("data :: "+data);` above if condition.

Comment: it's showing only else condition if condition not showing anything

Comment: can you please help me

Comment: where is else condition in your code? Use my edited code from answer and check toast again.

Comment: declaration String data="" it's taking null or what can you please check it out

Comment: Hi Manish debugging mode it's showing data variable value user found in if condition next moving to else.inside if condition not going

Comment: @user3436185 You mean, data variable has value "User Found" but you are seeing toast with "User not found"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing mistake here :

if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){

```
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                            startActivity(i);           

        }
```

in place of getApplicationContext() write :
 if(data.equalsIgnoreCase("User Found")){

```
                            Toast.makeText(Login.this,"Login Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class);

                            startActivity(i);
```